# Insert error in Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-pages

I am new in asp, i have an error in my code, can anyone help me please?

```
     protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew")) 
  { 
   TextBox txtUsername=(TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUsername"); 
   TextBox PASSWORD=(TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("PASSWORD"); 
   TextBox txtStatus = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStatus"); 
   TextBox txtE_MAIL = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtE_MAIL");

   customer.Insert(txtUsername.Text, PASSWORD, txtStatus.Text, txtE_MAIL.Text) ; 
     BindEmployeeDetails();
```

error picture is attached.[image]

Comment: What is the 'customer' instance ? show the code section where you are intializing the things

Comment: And you don't have the `.Text` property for your `PASSWORD TextBox object` because...??

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout for the Insert method.
2. Checkout the Class name of that page whether its Default or _Default.
3. Cross check in the very first line of the aspx file (Page Directive) where CodeBehind and Inherits  attributes are used.
4. Finally check Default.aspx.designer.cs,

Now match all the default's and its heirarchy. Correct that to Default. You code will run fine.

Update

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    _Default customer=new _Default();
    customer.Insert()//
}
```

Your problem is with these line. You are creating a new object of the _Default class inside the _Default class. That is assuming that it is accessing its own members. Means the code written inside the region

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{


}
```

and here its object customer is unable to find Insert(). I think you have some other class with same name. Instead of created a new object, You can mark it as partial class and access Insert() without using customer.Insert();

Your new code will be

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 //_Default customer=new _Default();// no need to write this
   // customer.Insert()// no need to write this too

// simply mark the class contaning Insert with "partial class _Default" and
//acess the Insert directly

Insert(txt1.text, txt2.text,...);

}
```

Comment: Can u explain in simple?

Comment: my class name is _Default

Comment: Your problem is with the page name. _Default and Default is the root cause. Can you upload somewhere and send me the link of the files ASPX and Codebehind so that I view them online

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33900/discussion-between-muhammad-saqib-and-amit-ranjan)